# Rails: ERROR bad Request-Line ` '

Tags: cookies, ruby-on-rails-4, terminal, request

I have a rails server. Everything is fine until recently I realise these strange error messages keep on repeating in terminal:

```
[2014-03-30 17:51:00] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 17:58:44] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:05:59] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:13:51] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:21:47] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:28:40] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:36:24] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:44:34] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:51:33] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 18:58:02] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 19:04:32] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 19:10:33] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
[2014-03-30 19:17:11] ERROR bad Request-Line ` '.
```

I have no idea what cause this problem. Anyone has this issue before please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**: This issue only happen with Chrome.

Comment: Sometimes removing temp cache may help. Stop rails server and run `rake tmp:clear` and restart the server again.

Comment: I tried to clear cache, remove chrome's cookies, restart server, rename session cookie name... but nothing works.

Comment: clearing the browser cookies/cache for localhost worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I don't have any insight why this issue is happening.

But this fix did work for me:

1. Run `rake tmp:clear`.
2. Restart the `rails server`.
3. Clear the chrome cache **and cookies**. (Clearing only the cache did not work for me.)
4. Restart chrome.

[image: chrome settings]

Credit: Kirti Thorat, emaillenin